# Datepicker not appearing when using javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to make the Datepicker widget appear by using a javascript file and it won't appear when I load the html file in a browser. I am also very new to coding in html/javascript.

The Datepicker appears when I include it in a script tag in the html, but doesn't appear when it is in a javascript file

HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDG</title>
    <meta name="description" content="web dev assignment" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pdg.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>

    <!-- datepicker files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Well, one code smell, your div is not inside a body tag.  Then again there are no html tags either so maybe you didn't paste your whole page

Comment: Aside from that, your `index.js` file is included before your jquery includes.....

Comment: Move this to right ABOVE your end body </body> tag. "<script src="index.js"></script>"

Comment: @shadoe2020 that worked! thank you!

Comment: It doesn't have to be at the end of the body, since the script is using a document ready.  It **does**, however, have to be after the jquery includes.